# How to prove these equations base on this following interior and exterior angle bisectors problem?

Tags: proof-writing, triangles

In the triangle $\triangle ABC$, length of $BC$ is larger than length of $AC$.

The interior angle bisector of $\angle C$ intersects $AB$ at $D$; and the exterior angle bisector of $\angle C$ intersects the extension of $AB$ at $E$.

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/2uo5aud.png]

How to prove that:

> $$|DE|= \frac{2abc}{a^2-b^2}$$

Thanks

Comment: I believe your diagram is incorrect. The external angle bisector at $C$ should be perpendicular to the internal angle bisector.

Comment: okay, thanks..I'll try to correct it later. @Blue, can you give me a link to theorem that state that internal and external bisector angle will be form a right angle? thanks

Comment: It may be that you are unclear about the definition of an exterior angle bisector. Of course, the *internal* bisector of $\angle C$ bisects a pair of vertical angles created by $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$. The *external* angle bisector, then, bisects the *other* pair of vertical angles created by those same lines. The fact that the two bisectors are perpendicular is an immediate consequence of the fact that the exterior and interior angles are supplementary.

Comment: Yes, I've just realized that no matter the value of angle C, we will get the external angle bisector and internal angle bisector of the same angle is always produced the right angle. But, the problem is how can we get the value like the above? it seems not possible to get a^2-b^2 from above problem?

Comment: I've found a solution using some trigonometry, but it seems overly-complicated. I'm looking for something more direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In $\triangle ABC$ 
$|AB|=c$,
$|BC|=a>|AC|=b$, 
internal bisector $|CD|$, 
external bisector $|CE|$.

Let $|AE|=u$, $|AD|=v$.

By the 
[Angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem#Theorem),

\begin{align} 
av&=b(c-v)
,\\
v&=\frac{bc}{a+b}
.
\end{align}

According the exterior angle bisector theorem, 
the external bisector of an angle of a triangle 
divides the opposite side externally 
in the ratio of the sides containing the angle,
hence

\begin{align} 
\frac{|BE|}{|AE|}&=\frac{|BC|}{|AC|}
,\\
\frac{u+c}u &= \frac ab
,\\
u&=\frac{bc}{a-b}
.
\end{align}

It follows that

\begin{align} 
|DE|&=u+v=
\frac{bc}{a-b}+\frac{bc}{a+b}
=\frac{2abc}{a^2-b^2}
.
\end{align}